# Knowing when Client has finished reading from the socket in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a client-server program in c where I have to send multiple image files from the server to the client. Is there any way for the server to know when the client has finished reading from socket, creating the image file locally, and successfully written to it? P.S. I already tried sending a message to the socket and when I try to read the socket from the server, the program hangs. Any help will be much appreciated. 
Here is a function from the Server code which sends the file to socket:

```
while(1)
{
  unsigned char buf[256] = {0};

  int n = fread(buf,1,256,fp);

  if(n>0) { send(sockfd,buf,n,0); }
  if(n<256) {
    if(feof(fp)) 
       printf("Sent to socket\n");
       break;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

char buf[5]
read(sockfd,buf,5);
if(strcmp(buf,"ready")==0) //send more files
```

And here is a function from the client to write to the file:

```
 FILE* fp;
 fp = fopen(file_path,"ab");
 char buf[256];
 int num;
 int total=0;
 while(( num = recv(sockfd,buf,256,0))>0)
 {
  total+=num;
  fwrite(buf,1,num,fp);
 }

 fclose(fp);

 write(sockfd,"ready",5);

 }
```

When I do a read on the server after one file transfer, the program hangs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The only way for the server to know is for the client to send a message back to the server. If your server is hanging while trying to read that message then you have not coded the reading correctly. Please show your actual code, or a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The server will hang in the read because it is a blocking call and will wait until it received something.

Comment: Yes, but I am making the client write the message "ready" into the socket; The server fails to read that.

Comment: HAve u tried closing the socket on the client side after the write() ?

Answer (score 5):

You problem is here in the client:

```
while(( num = recv(sockfd,buf,256,0))>0)
```

`recv()` will only return `0` at end-of-file - ie when the server shuts down the sending side of the socket.  However your server isn't doing that - it's waiting for a response from the client.  This means you deadlock.

If you want to send multiple images in the one connection, you need to send your client some information to allow it to tell when one image ends.  One way to do this is to first send your client the size of the file it should expect, then the file data.  The client can then keep track of how many bytes it's recieved, and send the "ready" reponse after that.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely try that.

Answer (score 2):

You need a kind of protocol to allow :

- the server to tell the client that all has been written
- the client to tell the server that all has been read

If you only send one file, the simplest way is to use `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR)` server side after all data has beed sent. That way the client will get a 0 as return from `recv` signaling end of data and will be able to send its acknowledgement. But you can no longer write on the socket server side.

If you want to be able to send more than one file, you will have to imagine a cleverer protocol. A common one would be to send blocs of data preceded by their size

```
short sz = htons(n);  /* deals with possible endianness problems */
send(sockfd, &sz, sizeof(short), 0)
send(sockfd, buf, n);
```

And a `sz == 0` (with no buf ...) would signal end of data

This would still be a simple protocol with no error recovery, but at least it can work when no incident happens.